# TortoiseGit missing icon overlay for only files

Tags: windows, tortoisegit

Running into an odd issue where icon overlays for cloned repos are displayed on all folders but missing on the files. There's currently 9 tortoise and 8 one drive entries in the ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers in regedit but the tortoise ones are all at the top, having a "  " at the start of each name.

I had seen that too many entries would cause the icons not to display, but since I still see the overlays on folders I was hesitant to start deleting items from the registry. Is this the same issue or could there be some other factor is icons are still partially working?

Answer (score 2):

This looks as if the folder is excluded from status generation (i.e., `show excluded folders as normal`).

Please look at TortoiseGit settings and check `Icon overlay settings` (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-overlay)

Please also see https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#ovlnotall

Comment: @user1267983 Does this answer your question? if yes please consider to accept it (that's the way to say thank you on SO) or add a comment.